# infinitive-to grammar

Tags: meaning, grammar, to-infinitive

I learned that I can not put *-ing* form after the *infinitive-to*; I should put *base form of verb*
after the *infinitive-to*.

However, in this sentence, (this is from my textbook.)

They were able to dedicate all of their time **to** **ensuring** that I did well in school.

I can see **ing** form is used after infinitive **to**.

I am curious that why this sentence is grammatical even though it violates the constraint, and I want to know if I can change given sentence into *They were able to dedicate all of their time **to ensure** that I did well in school.*

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in non-native English speaking countries, especially in India, even teachers teach wrong! I'm a victim!

*infinite -to* does not take *-ing* - plain **wrong!**

It's called a *verb pattern.* And, there are many verbs that take the *-ing* form after them. In fact, it's *gerund.*

The commonest is -

> I'm looking forward to ***meeting*** you.

Interesting? Learn more on [verb patterns here on Cambridge.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns/verb-patterns-verb-infinitive-or-verb-ing) Not just *-ing,* you'll learn more on that!

Another blog that answers it completely [is here.](http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/grammar-can-a-gerund-be-used-after-to/) It describes three *possible* rules on that.